# How to get internet speed in React native for android and iOS?

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native, mobile, hybrid-mobile-app

I was using netinfo library but not found internet speed using cellular or wifi network like 100 kbps/1 mbps

I tried https://www.npmjs.com/package/@react-native-community/netinfo,and https://github.com/TSjianjiao/react-native-network-speed
but facing issue with adding
'Add new RNNetworkSpeedPackage() to the list returned by the getPackages() method'
Not able to find getPackages in MainActivity.java

Answer (score 0):

You can try the netflix api speed test.

Answer (score 0):

Check if this npm package fulfils your requirement.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-network-speed